# no connection to SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql-server

I have installed VS2019, MSSQL Server 2014, and SQL Server Management Studio release 16.5.3 and got SQL_ERROR via Msg variable [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. What is the problem? I have no firewall. Database running of same computer.

```
int main()
{
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success" << endl;
    
    if( SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success" << endl;

    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    if(SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
        cout << "success" << endl;

    cout << "Attempting connection to SQL Server..." << endl;

    #define SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN 1000
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];
    //SQLCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];
    switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        //(SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost, 1433;DATABASE=master;Trusted=true;",
        (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=BLACK4-PC\\SQLEXPRESS, 1433;DATABASE=My_BASE;Trusted=true;",
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
    {
        case SQL_SUCCESS:
        {
            cout << "Successfully connected to SQL Server" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        {
            cout << " Could not connect to SQL Server 1" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case SQL_ERROR:
        {
            cout << " Could not connect to SQL Server 2" << endl;

            SQLSMALLINT i = 1, MsgLen;
            SQLWCHAR SqlState[6];
            SQLRETURN rc2;
            SQLINTEGER NativeError[1];
            SQLWCHAR Msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH];
            rc2 = SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle, i, SqlState, NativeError,
                Msg, sizeof(Msg), &MsgLen);
            break;
        }

    }
    
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it can see the machine but the connection gets killed. Does the server have a firewall or do you have some sort of network ACL's?

Comment: Does other database software work with the same connection string?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I no have network ACL's, I have my PC, installed MS SQL Server, VS2019.

Comment: I changed port to value 54268 (taken from server log) and now have another error [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.

Comment: Instead of `Trusted=true;` have you tried `Trusted_Connection=yes;`?

Comment: Also, "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" is quite old and isn't even supported on Windows 10. You may wish to uninstall it and install [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for support, I changed to Trusted_Connection=yes; and all are work now.